# An abandoned Connect Wall

Tags: word, knowledge, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 prompts below may be separated into 4 groups.
Additionally, there is a word absent from the wall which may be placed in all four of those groups.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Beaver** | **Cheat** | **Cod** | **Direction** |
| **Elf** | **Fuzzy Wuzzy** | **Jackson** | **Krill** |
| **Mountain Meadow** | **Negate** | **Outer Space** | **Sternal** |
| **Strait** | **Sum** | **U** | **Waxer** |

**Can you identify the four groups?**
**What new word can be placed in all four of those groups?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This tricky Connect Wall resolves like so:

> Group 1: **Band names missing numbers**
>
>  **One** Direction
>  U**2**
>  Jackson **5**
>  Sum **41**
>
>  Group 2: **[Crayola colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Crayola_crayon_colors)**
>
>  Beaver
>  Fuzzy Wuzzy
>  Mountain Meadow
>  Outer Space
>
>  Group 3: **Can remove the chemical symbol of a [noble gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas) to form another word**
>
>  C[He]at = CAT without He (Helium)
>  [Ne]gate = GATE without Ne (Neon)
>  Ste[Rn]al = STEAL without Rn (Radon)
>  Wa[Xe]r = WAR without Xe (Xenon)
>
>  *([Kr]ill was a cruel red herring in this category!)*
>
>  Group 4: **First and last letters are consecutive in the English alphabet**
>
>  **C**o**D**
>  **E**l**F**
>  **K**ril**L**
>  **S**trai**T**

The word that links all four categories is:

> **MAROON**
>  Maroon **5**
>  The colour 'maroon'
>  M[Ar]oon = MOON without Ar (Argon)
>  **M**aroo**N**

This also fits with the title, since:

> to 'maroon' somebody is to *abandon* them!

Comment: That is indeed correct, I originally designed it having a bit more to Group 3, but it fits just as well nonetheless!

Comment: @Auribouros Aha, I see what you've done there! Will edit...